# PHP how to iterate through a WP Object

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I'm really new to PHP. From what i've learnt/read. To iterate through an object in php you use `->` and to iterate through an array you `["itemInArray"]`. This might sound stupid, but how to I grab something out of this object below? Say, the `post_content`?

I'm already within a `foreach` loop thats looped through a multidimensional array. Which looks like:

```
foreach ($key as $b=>$test) {
 var_dump($test["post_content"]);
}
```

-

My object:

```
object(WP_Post)#7239 (24) {
  ["ID"]=>
  int(2127)
  ["post_author"]=>
  string(1) "5"
  ["post_date"]=>
  string(19) "2016-04-29 09:45:55"
  ["post_date_gmt"]=>
  string(19) "2016-04-29 09:45:55"
  ["post_content"]=>
  string(313) "<p class="p1"><span class="s1">Some dummy content</span></p>
<p class="p1"><em>Support from whateves</em></p>"
  ["post_title"]=>
  string(12) "The Title"
  ["post_excerpt"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["post_status"]=>
  string(7) "publish"
  ["comment_status"]=>
  string(6) "closed"
  ["ping_status"]=>
  string(6) "closed"
  ["post_password"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["post_name"]=>
  string(12) "the-title"
  ["to_ping"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["pinged"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["post_modified"]=>
  string(19) "2016-11-24 14:34:01"
  ["post_modified_gmt"]=>
  string(19) "2016-11-24 14:34:01"
  ["post_content_filtered"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["post_parent"]=>
  int(0)
  ["guid"]=>
  string(66) "http://www.localhost:8080/?post_type=creator&#038;p=2127"
  ["menu_order"]=>
  int(0)
  ["post_type"]=>
  string(17) "creator"
  ["post_mime_type"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["comment_count"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["filter"]=>
  string(3) "raw"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick.

`echo $test->post_content;`

The differences between PHP arrays and objects is this:

Array:

```
$array = new Array();
$array['test'] = 'test';
echo $array['test'];
```

Object:

```
$object = new stdClass();
$object->test = 'test';
echo $object->test;
```